# PHP Copy function not working

Tags: php, file, function, copy

I'm trying to use copy function in php to copy an image from a url to my server.
The function opens the right folders on the server but the file is not in the last folder. its just empty.

Here's my piece of code:

```
$srcfile="http://domain.com/images2/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
$dstfile="/images/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
mkdir(dirname($dstfile), 0777, true);
copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

Any idea on why could this be?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you having the correct chmod permissions? Do you get any errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?

Comment: How do I apply error_reporting?

Comment: Write the code posted above on top of your PHP file (after opening tags obv)

Comment: Are you sure that "fopen wrappers" are enabled, per the PHP changelog note next to v4.3.0?  allow_url_fopen, http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$srcfile="http://domain.com/images2/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
$dstfile=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
mkdir(dirname($dstfile), 0777, true);
copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$srcfile="http://domain.com/images2/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
```

I would suggest to determine the above file location from the copy function file. Write the jump location from there. e.g

```
$srcfile="../images2/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
```

Same goes with your destination file.

```
$dstfile="../images/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
```

The deeper the folder the more jump you need. e.g.

```
$dstfile="../../../images/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
```

Sometime writing full URL will not work because it will be like this :

```
$dstfile="http://domain.com/http://domain.com/images2/2014/01/02/1.jpg";
```

Which is just a repeating URL.