# Download file with php and save it to folder

Tags: php

I want download this link with PHP and save to folder
it's a `xlsx` file

`http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0`

I use flower cods bout it's not true.

```
file_put_contents('A.xlsx', file_get_contents('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0'));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511889/php-copy-function-not-working that should do it.

Comment: make sure allow_url_fopen=On in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive version.

```
function saveExternal($source,$local){
  $s = file_get_contents($source);
  $f = fopen($local,'w+');
  fwrite($f,$s);
  fclose($f);
}
saveExternal('http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0','A.xlsx');
```

Comment: tanks, This code was downloaded but will not open the file A.xlsx

Comment: Hmm.. tried several different methods and the file keeps coming back as corrupt or empty. Good luck! May have something to do with the language, you may have to find the right mix of headers and use `readfile`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938190/php-force-downloading-xlsx-file-corrupt https://www.google.com/search?q=header+type+xlsx&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I could not do something, you get me?

Comment: @user3262996 I tried. It's a very specific answer you seek and I do not know it. I attached several good leads to pursue.